# прилипание колонки при прокрутке страницы

Tags: html, jquery, css

К левой колонке подключен скрипт,при которой левая колонка при прокрутке прилипает то к верхнему краю,то к нижнему. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему вылетает из блока и лишние границы появляются при прокрутке?

```js
(function() {
  var a = document.querySelector('#left'),
    b = null,
    K = null,
    Z = 0,
    P = 0,
    N = 0; // если у P ноль заменить на число, то блок будет прилипать до того, как верхний край окна браузера дойдёт до верхнего края элемента, если у N — нижний край дойдёт до нижнего края элемента. Может быть отрицательным числом
  window.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);

  function Ascroll() {
    var Ra = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
      R1bottom = document.querySelector('#text').getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    if (Ra.bottom < R1bottom) {
      if (b == null) {
        var Sa = getComputedStyle(a, ''),
          s = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < Sa.length; i++) {
          if (Sa[i].indexOf('overflow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('padding') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('border') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('outline') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('box-shadow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('background') == 0) {
            s += Sa[i] + ': ' + Sa.getPropertyValue(Sa[i]) + '; '
          }
        }
        b = document.createElement('div');
        b.className = "stop";
        b.style.cssText = s + ' box-sizing: border-box; width: ' + a.offsetWidth + 'px;';
        a.insertBefore(b, a.firstChild);
        var l = a.childNodes.length;
        for (var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
          b.appendChild(a.childNodes[1]);
        }
        a.style.height = b.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
        a.style.padding = '0';
        a.style.border = '0';
      }
      var Rb = b.getBoundingClientRect(),
        Rh = Ra.top + Rb.height,
        W = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        R1 = Math.round(Rh - R1bottom),
        R2 = Math.round(Rh - W);
      if (Rb.height > W) {
        if (Ra.top < K) { // скролл вниз
          if (R2 + N > R1) { // не дойти до низа
            if (Rb.bottom - W + N <= 0) { // подцепиться
              b.className = 'sticky';
              b.style.top = W - Rb.height - N + 'px';
              Z = N + Ra.top + Rb.height - W;
            } else {
              b.className = 'stop';
              b.style.top = -Z + 'px';
            }
          } else {
            b.className = 'stop';
            b.style.top = -R1 + 'px';
            Z = R1;
          }
        } else { // скролл вверх
          if (Ra.top - P < 0) { // не дойти до верха
            if (Rb.top - P >= 0) { // подцепиться
              b.className = 'sticky';
              b.style.top = P + 'px';
              Z = Ra.top - P;
            } else {
              b.className = 'stop';
              b.style.top = -Z + 'px';
            }
          } else {
            b.className = '';
            b.style.top = '';
            Z = 0;
          }
        }
        K = Ra.top;
      } else {
        if ((Ra.top - P) <= 0) {
          if ((Ra.top - P) <= R1) {
            b.className = 'stop';
            b.style.top = -R1 + 'px';
          } else {
            b.className = 'sticky';
            b.style.top = P + 'px';
          }
        } else {
          b.className = '';
          b.style.top = '';
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        a.children[0].style.width = getComputedStyle(a, '').width
      }, false);
    }
  }
})()
```

```css
#content {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #969696;
  padding: 10px;
}
/*правая колонка*/
#text { 
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #969696;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
/*для jquery*/ 
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
}
.stop {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<div style="clear:both;"></div>  
<div id="content">
  <!-- content -->
  <div id="left">
   <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
  </div>
  <!-- left off (закрыт) -->
  <div id="text">
    <!-- text-->
    правая колонка 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br> 1
    <br>
  </div>
<div style="clear:both; padding-bottom:0.25em"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем вы сделали обработчик и на window и на document.body? если один убрать, то вроде бы все ок

Comment: @yolosora вообще взяла готовый скрипт и как обычно не работает... то есть нужно один из них убрать?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать)

Comment: @yolosora не помогает

Comment: В каких ситуациях блок должен быть снизу, а в каких сверху?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в коде при прокрутке добавляется другой контейнер, от которого пляшет событие scroll
Я не разбирался в Вашем коде (наверное это причина, что не отвечают на Ваш вопрос, это видимо из конструктора какого-то).
Я составил другой код, для наглядности. Для простоты не стал добавлять функцию при которой останавливается левый блок при прокрутке вниз, потому как в Вашем примере он тоже не останавливается. Посмотрите код, там понятно всё, может ответ будет полезен. Обратите также внимание, что в отличие от Вашего примера класс `.sticky` присваивается левому блоку, а не вновь созданному, как в Вашем примере.

```js
(function stickDiv() {
var content = document.getElementById('content'); //весь контент
var leftDiv = document.getElementById('left'); //левый блок
var rightDiv = document.getElementById('text'); //правй блок
var leftParent = document.getElementById('parent');
document.onscroll = function() {
    if (leftDiv.clientHeight - rightDiv.clientHeight > 0) {
        console.log('правый блок меньше');
        return
    };
    var sizeCheck = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 
     leftDiv.clientHeight;
    if (sizeCheck <= 0) scrollSmaller()
    else scrollBigger();

    function scrollBigger() {
        var upperEdge = content.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        if (upperEdge <= 0) //если верхняя граница блока '#content' уходит вверх
        {
            leftDiv.setAttribute('class', 'sticky')
        } else leftDiv.removeAttribute('class'); // присвоить левому блоку атрибут "class =  'sticky'"
    };

    function scrollSmaller() {
        var upperParentEdge = leftParent.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        if (upperParentEdge <= sizeCheck) {
            leftDiv.setAttribute('class', 'stickybottom')
        } else leftDiv.removeAttribute('class');
    };
}
})();
```

```css
#content {
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
#left {
width: 200px;
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #969696;
padding: 10px;
}
#parent {
height: auto;
float: left;
border: 1px dashed #f00;
}
/*правая колонка*/

#text {
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 250px;
border-radius: 8px;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px #969696;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 10px;
}
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 3px;
z-index: 101;
}
.stickybottom {
position: fixed;
bottom: 3px;
z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
       <div style="clear:both;">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- content -->
        <div id="parent">
            <div id="left">
                Левая колонка
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                1
                <br/>
                2
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- left off (закрыт) -->
        <div id="text">
            Правая колонка
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            1
            <br/>
            2
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<div style="clear:both; padding-bottom:0.25em">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо,Ваш код работает!а можете еще подсказать, как сделать  что бы прилипала нижняя часть колонки после прокрутки?

Comment: Я изменил функцию, чтобы она работала с прилипанием нижней части. Правда не вижу как это сработает. Теперь левый блок прилипает в зависимости от положения главного блока #content, а не правого блока как ранее. Опять надо повториться, чтобы Вы были осторожнее с экспериментами. Этот ответ для наглядности и применять его на своём сайте надо с осторожностью, по крайней мере, понимая что происходит. Потому что в других частях Вашего кода могут быть другие зависимости и неизвестно, какие атрибуты, классы  и события также подключены. Особенно при использовании конструкторов, и библиотек.

Comment: Хороший учебник и как раз на нужной странице :-) https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window

Comment: подскажите у stickybottom параметры не прописаны в css

Comment: .stickybottom {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 3px;
    z-index: 101;
} забыл... Там ещё непонятно по z-index,зачем он.

Comment: тогда начинают двигаться один вверх,другои вниз

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75083/discussion-between---and-).